# How can I resolve "Could not rename the file cache/normal/www.example.com/_.html on your system" error?

Tags: uri, caching

I have enabled [boost](https://www.drupal.org/project/boost) module as well clean url's also I got below error at `admin/reports/dblog` section:

> Could not rename the file cache/normal/www.example.com/_.html on your system (It comes sometimes.).
>
> The file permissions could not be set on `cache/normal/www.example.com/test_.html`.

I have set permissions for cache folder is 755.

Comment: what's the user your apache runs with ?

Comment: Hi remy thanks for your quick replay.www-data is the user,is there any chance to website crash for above error?

Comment: and to what user belong your files and folders ?

Comment: i'm login admin as user id "1" then accessing website and through ftp i'm accessing files

Comment: i'm talking about the user of the file system ;) is this the same as the apache user ?

Comment: make sure you're filesystem setup is correct. [drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924)